# Alternative to google maps

Tags: google-maps

NET app, where I allow Users to map a location using google maps and then use those location on the front end of my app to again use these locations to map a location.

This works fine, but the customer was looking for an alternative in case the user does not have Javascript enabled ?

I wasnt aware of any alternatives, but if someone does can they please point me the right way

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180623/which-are-the-best-geo-coding-apis-available-for-free

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If user has no JavaScript enabled, you can use flash version or even static Google Maps images

- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/
- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but did you look into the Static Maps API?

[Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

Comment: Sorry the question in short is. If the user does not have javascript enabled I need an alternative, it turns out from above google map actually provides this which I didn't know