# How to get the latitude and longitude from the address in python quickly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation, openstreetmap, nominatim

I have used the code for finding the latitude and longitude from the given address:

```
     locator = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeocoder")  # holds the Geocoding service, Nominatim
     geocode = RateLimiter(locator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001)
    data['MBR_location'] = data['MBR_Full_Address'].apply(lambda x: geocode(x))
     data['Prov_location'] = data['Prov_Full_Address'].apply(lambda x: geocode(x))
```

But it takes so much time to produce the latitude and longitude. For example, in this way, it needs 3 hours for getting the latitude and longitude from only 10k ID. **Is there any way to get the results faster way?** Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it takes so long because you are using OSM's public Nominatim instance and the [usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/) only allows *one request per second*. So either switch to a [different Nominatim instance](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Alternatives_.2F_Third-party_providers) or [install your own local Nominatim server](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/).

Comment: is there any way to get the latitude and longitude from the address without using Nominatim?

Comment: Yes, you can use any other geocoding service. It doesn't have to be Nominatim. But such recommendations are out of scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: is that service is paid or free? Could you kindly tell me any other free geocoding service?

Comment: That service? Which service? I didn't mention any specific one. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8180637/1340631 or https://gisgeography.com/geocoders/. And there are several more, I guess.